# TaskbarItemInfo does not show Indeterminate ProgressState

Tags: wpf, xaml, progress-bar, taskbar

I have made a simple example of my issue. There is a window having its DataContext bount to MainWindowViewModel class. The window contains a Grid with a Button and a ProgressBar. The Button's command is bount to a ViewModel's RelayCommand that at first executes an increment of an integer property "Percent" from 0 to 100. The progressBar shows the progress just fine! The window contains a TaskBarItemInfo property, and the latter has two properties: a ProgressValue bount to a double property "Count", and a ProgressState bount to a TaskbarItemProgressState property "State", all properties in the in the MainWindowViewModel. The TaskbarItemInfo shows also just fine the increment from 0 to 1.

But in the second part of the initial method the progress becomes indeterminate for 5 seconds. While that shows just fine in the progressBar, it does not in the TaskBar. I have used both a Converter from boolean to TaskbarItemProgressState to the Path of the ProgressState property (IsIndeterminate), and a binding to a separate property State, as shown to the code below.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ProgressState.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProgressState"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BoolToProgressStateConverter x:Key="boolToProgressStateConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
        <TaskbarItemInfo ProgressValue="{Binding Count, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                         ProgressState="{Binding State, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <!--ProgressState="{Binding IsIndeterminate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource boolToProgressStateConverter}}"-->
    </Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Start progress" Grid.Row="0" Height="30" Width="100"
                Command="{Binding Start}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Height="20" Margin="10 0"
                     Value="{Binding Percent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                     IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsIndeterminate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Shell;

namespace ProgressState
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private double count;
        private bool isIndeterminate;
        private int percent;
        private bool isEnabled = true;
        private TaskbarItemProgressState state;

        public RelayCommand Start { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Start = new RelayCommand(OnStart, CanStart);
        }

        public TaskbarItemProgressState State
        {
            get
            {
                if (IsIndeterminate)
                {
                    state = TaskbarItemProgressState.Indeterminate;
                }
                else
                {
                    state = TaskbarItemProgressState.Normal;
                }
                return state; 
            }
        }

        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return isEnabled; 
            }
            set 
            {
                if (value != isEnabled)
                {
                    isEnabled = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsEnabled));
                }
            }
        }


        public bool IsIndeterminate
        {
            get 
            {
                return isIndeterminate; 
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != isIndeterminate)
                {
                    isIndeterminate = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsIndeterminate));
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(State));
                }
            }
        }
        

        public int Percent
        {
            get
            {
                return percent; 
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != percent)
                {
                    percent = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Percent));
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Count));
                }
            }
        }

        public double Count
        {
            get 
            {
                count = Percent / 100d;
                return count;
            }
        }


        private bool CanStart()
        {
            return true;
        }

        private async void OnStart()
        {
            IsEnabled = false;
            Percent = 0;
            
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (Percent != 100)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    Percent += 2;
                    
                }

                IsIndeterminate = true;
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                IsIndeterminate = false;
            });

            IsEnabled = true;

        }
    }
}
```

**BoolToProgressStateConverter.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Shell;

namespace ProgressState
{
    class BoolToProgressStateConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool boolean)
            {
                if (boolean == true)
                {
                    return TaskbarItemProgressState.Indeterminate;
                }
                else if (boolean == false)
                {
                    return TaskbarItemProgressState.Normal;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }

            }
            return TaskbarItemProgressState.Normal;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not seeing your issue.  When I take your code and run it, I see indeterminate state for 5 seconds on the TaskbarItem (fyi, I'm running Windows 10 1909, VS2019, WPF .NET Framework 4.7.2): https://drive.google.com/file/d/12y4tEATgVxegoYz6JZXSLPzw5qGpF_Xc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am using exactly the same configuration as yours, but with .NET v4.6.1. After re-configuring it to use v4.7.2 (and 4.8), I still get nothing in the taskbar...
At least I know the code itself works.
Thank you for your time...

Comment: I would try running your sample code on a different machine then to confirm it might be an issue with your system.  Good luck!

Comment: I just tried it on the machine of a colleague, and it works fine.
I will make another comment if I manage to find, what the issue is with my machine...
Thanx again!

Comment: I encountered the same problem, my environment is Win10 + WPF + .Net5. Both of my projects will do this, one of the projects seems to be working fine at times, and I'm getting the impression that it's some kind of bug.

Comment: I had this issue on RDP. Apparently, there are some optimizations that prevent the "pulsing" from being shown.

Comment: Had "RDP issue" on my side, thanks @Monsignor